# Record counts where column contains char(x)

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, char, character

I need to count the number of records where a column (varchar(x)) contains a particular character, for all ASCII characters 1-255. This is what I have so far (in a proc)...

```
DECLARE @CHAR TINYINT = 1
CREATE TABLE #CHARCOUNTS  (CHAR TINYINT, COUNT INT)

WHILE @CHAR < 255

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #CHARCOUNTS(CHAR, COUNT) VALUES (@CHAR,(SELECT COUNT (ID) FROM MyTable WHERE CHARINDEX(CHAR(@CHAR), MyColumn) > 0))
    SET @CHAR = @CHAR + 1
END 

SELECT CHAR, COUNT FROM #CHARCOUNTS
```

This returns a result set telling me there are X records containing `CHAR(1)`, X records containing `CHAR(2)` and so on, however the query is taking several minutes to complete on approx 5 million records as I guess it has to traverse every record 255 times. Any suggestions for a more efficient/faster way of doing this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this **SET BASED APPROACH**.

Use a `Recursive CTE` to generate the numbers.

Then use `cross apply` to find the `count` of each `char` in your column. In a single shot you can find all the `char` count and in a 5 millions record also `single` insert instead of `255` inserts, so this will have a better performance.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT 1 chars
         UNION ALL
         SELECT chars + 1
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  chars < 255)
INSERT INTO #CHARCOUNTS
            (CHAR,COUNT)
SELECT chars,
       [count]
FROM   cte
       CROSS apply (SELECT Count (ID) [count]
                    FROM   MyTable
                    WHERE  Charindex(Char(chars), MyColumn) > 0) cs
OPTION (maxrecursion 256)
```

**Note:** There are so many ways to generate number's since the count here is very less i have chosen `Recursive CTE` over the other methods. Check [***here***](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) for more info